# Why doesn't timeout execute in Safari when it fails to open in app?

Tags: javascript, ios, timeout, app-store, deep-linking

I've written the following javascript for Safari on iOS:

```
window.location = "myapp://";
setTimeout(function() {
  window.location = "itms-apps://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/myapp";
}, 9000);
```

So the first line tries to open an app using a URI scheme. If app is installed the user is shown a dialog to confirm opening in app, the user then taps yes and the app opens. In this case the timeout code never executes because the javascript has stopped executing once the app opens(which will happen in less than 9 seconds). So this is fine.

If the app is not installed you get the famous "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid" error and then .... it stays like that forever. But I have a timeout there too which should have timed out after 9 seconds and the Appstore should have opened, right? So why is the Appstore not opening after 9 seconds? Why is my time out code never executing?